# Associated prime ideals and localization of Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory* he states in Thm 6.2 that:

> If $A$ is a Noetherian ring which contains a multiplicative subset $S$, then for an $A$-module $M$ we have: $$\mathrm{Ass}(M_S)=\mathrm{Ass}(M)\cap\mathrm{Spec}(A_S).$$

Here $Ass(M)$ is the set of all **associated prime** ideals (an ideal is prime also an annihilator of some $x\in M$) of $M$ and $Spec(A_S)$ is seen to be a subspace of $Spec(A)$ since there's a bijection between prime ideals of $A$ contained in $A-S$ and those of $A_S$.

In the text in order to prove "$\subseteq$" direction, choose $P\in Ass(M_S)$ and since $p=P\cap A$ is already a prime ideal only need to prove $p=ann_{A}(m),m\in M$. And any $s\in S\subset A_S$ is a unit so $P$ can be choosen to be the form $ann_{A_S}(x),x\in M$.

**Here's what I'm confused about in the proof**: he states that $p$ is finitely generated by Noether property of $A$ then $\exists t\in S,\ p=ann_A(tx)$.

My thought is:

By definition of $p$, $p=ann_{A_S}(x)\cap A=ann_A(x)\subseteq ann_A(tx)$ for any $t\in S$.

If $atx=0$, then $attx=0\Rightarrow at\in p$, i.e. with $t\in S,t\notin p$ we have $a\in ann_A(tx)\Rightarrow a\in p$ thus $ann_A(tx)\subseteq p,\forall t\in S$. Then it seems like we get $p=ann_A(tx)$ without finiteness of $p$. **So where's the mistake and how does the finiteness of $p$ is needed?**

Comment: $p$ is not equal to $ann_A(x)$.

Comment: I see,the symbol "$\cap$" makes me think $A\rightarrow A_S$ is injective but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $p$ is generated by $p_i$ then $p_ix=0\in M_S\Leftrightarrow \exists s_i\in S,s_ip_ix=0\in M$

Take $t=\Pi_is_i,a\in A$ if $atx=0$ then $at\in A$ and $at\in ann_{A_S}(x)$ by definition so $at\in p\Rightarrow a\in p$,that is $ann_{A}(tx)\subseteq p$.

But any $b=\sum_i r_ip_i\in p,r_i\in A$ must annihilates $tx$ in $M$,that is $p\subseteq ann_A(tx)$